# add two dll's to msvc 2010 application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use libcurl library in my application.
when i start my application, it asks for libcurl.dll and zlib1.dll
to exist in the same folder. when i add them everything works fine but i want to include
them to the executable.

[image]

how can i statically add both dll's to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot statically link dlls into an executable. The purpose of dynamic libraries is to be loaded dynamically during runtime from an external image (dll file). You should check whether curl and zlib provide proper static libraries and link against them instead of lib stubs for the dlls.

Consider that linking against static external libraries makes your binary potentially vulnerable against any security issues in statically linked blobs. That means that you will have to update any binary you statically linked against those libraries instead of simply updating the libraries themselves.

Comment: So am i currently using a non static library?

Comment: Visual Studio understands two types of link libraries: pure static lib files which are directly linked into the result of the compilation or "stub" lib files which simply proxy requests to the appropriate dll file. You are using the latter. I looked into the msvc zip of libcurl on http://curl.haxx.se/download.html for you and there is a static lib file in the lib folder. You have to specify it instead of what you have right now in the project properties. Same for the zlib file.